# Error Converting JSON to array PHP

Tags: php, json, string

Hello So i have this call.

```
$preciobitcoin = curlCall('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/');
```

and i can perfectly get `$preciobitcoin['last'].`

but this one

```
$preciodolar = curlCall('https://s3.amazonaws.com/dolartoday/data.json');
```

return as a string instead of an array

this is the code of the function which is not working
this is the code of the function which is not working

```
function curlCall($url, $params = null, $contentType = 'application/json', $options = array()) {
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);

if (!is_null($params) && !is_null($options['key']) && !is_null($options['sig'])) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: '.$contentType, 'key: '.$options['key'], 'sig: '.$options['sig']));
    //
} else if (!is_null($params) && !empty($params)) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: '.$contentType));
} else {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: '.$contentType));
}

// Allow for custom requests
if (isset($options['custom_request']) && !empty($options['custom_request'])) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $options['custom_request']);
}

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; cryptoGlance ' . CURRENT_VERSION . '; PHP/' . phpversion() . ')');

$curlExec = curl_exec($curl);
if ($curlExec === false || curl_errno($curl)) {
    $data = array();
} else {
    $data = json_decode($curlExec, true);
}

if (empty($data)) {
    // return non-jsonfied data
    return $curlExec;
}

curl_close($curl);

return $data;
```

}

Comment: show how you parse the result in both cases by editing your post

Comment: Did you try to use `json_decode` to parse the json string to array?

Comment: yes, the variable becomes null..

Comment: `echo $preciodolar->USD->transferencia` try this

Comment: It's wierd it's like the function does not recognize it as an json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably is an encoding issue. Here is an example that works correctly on my localhost.

```
$str = file_get_contents( 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/dolartoday/data.json' );
var_dump( mb_detect_encoding( $str ) );

$str = mb_convert_encoding( $str, "UTF-8" );
var_dump( mb_detect_encoding( $str ) );

var_dump( json_decode( $str ));
```

Answer (score 0):

a quick call to json_last_error() returns this

Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

possibly there are a few hidden bad chars (not utf8) in that file.

Comment: I was thinking that.. is there anything i could do on my side?

Comment: $text = iconv("utf-8", "utf-8//ignore", $text);